# Hook keyboard not registering first key when typing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've a hook keyboard class created and it's working fine. It's created to catch when keys are typed in T-SQL editor for VS 2012 and 2010. The only problem I got is that in VS2012 it's not registering my first keystroke. It's not global hook, it's apps. In VS2010 it's working great. I've checked everything and couldn't find where to look for this problem. After you type in the first character window form is showing and then you type in the second character and that one is shown nicely. On first keystroke that is not registered form is shown as it should just as I made it, but somehow I am not sure what is happening in 2012 and my first key is not being shown.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did You test only inside vs, or Your hooking application alone ?

Comment: Inside VS, I am trying only to hook to T-SQL editor window.

Comment: I am not sure if this has anything to do with it but Form.Show() and Form.Refresh() are being called at some point when Form should be shown and then my key is being swallowed. Really not sure if this is the main reason but just wanted to post that info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect the logging to a file and test without vs. The app alone.

Comment: App alone is working fine, I've tested it. On windows forms this works great, it's even working nice with VS 2010. So my guess is that maybe Vs2012 is having WPF forms and not sure what is happening exactly and why on Show() key is being swallowed.

Comment: Right, i supposed the same.

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve this with implementing totally different code for keyboard hook. Thank you for trying to help me with this. Now the only thing left for me to do is stop processing keys for inactive window. Do you maybe know how to accomplish that? Thanks again

Comment: What Do You mean ?

Do not understand .  You have at least one active window. Don't You have ? So, this window is Your active one, any input control has the focus and each letter typed will be logged ( actually also, the window has no input control focussed but You just want to fly over the keyboard )......

Comment: I have T-SQL editor that is active and popup form that was inactive but it's shown. Anyway I was able to solve this with SendKeys.Send and then forward that first character that was swallowed only when form was shown for the first time. Thanks mate for your help. I appreciate it.